# image cropping tool without javascript

Tags: php, html, upload, crop

I have built an image upload with the ability to crop an image from its center with php. 
It works as it should.

Now, I want to provide the user a "*dragabble div*" which he can place onto the image to crop the selected part.

I know that there are a lot of javascript packages containing such functions, but i want to try this without js.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: As far as i'm, aware, you can't do this without JavaScript.

Comment: You might be to do this with Flash, but that seems to be on its way out.  I don't see this being possible with just PHP/CSS.